# Code coverage Cobertura report for WCS projects (Websphere Commmerce Server )

Tags: ant, sonarqube, code-coverage, cobertura, wcs

Is it possible to create a code coverage Cobertura report and get it published on Sonar Dashboard for Websphere Commmerce Server (WCS) projects ? I understand that the pre-requisite is that the team should have written the Junit test cases but still wondering whether code coverage report is possible to generate ?

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumptions that

1. a Websphere Commerce Server project is written in Java
2. the project contains unit tests that are executed during the build
3. a code coverage report is generated during the run of unit tests and pointed to during the analysis

Then the answer is yes.